# Why does core code use ::class to get class name as string?

Tags: magento2

Many places in the core code that need to use the name of a class as a string will use it as `\Magento\Module\Classname::class` rather than simply `'\Magento\Module\Classname'`.

The benefit is clear if you've imported the class with `use`, in which case it is a shortcut to repeating the full namespace, but in many instances `::class` is used even with the fully-qualified name. This seems to be most common in test classes, but it's not only true there.

What is the reason for this pattern?

Edit: Franck Garnier pointed out in an earlier version of answer that this is required by the [coding standards](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/coding-standards/code-standard-php.html), but that just pushes the question back a level. Why do the standards require this (particularly in contrast to an absolute class name string literal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to explain the use of `::class`.

Magento 2 uses `::class` because it is specified in the framework's coding standard.

The Magento 2 documentation page reference is here : https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/coding-standards/code-standard-php.html

> Class name resolution standard
>
> For class name resolution, use the `::class` keyword instead of a string
>   literal for every class name reference outside of that class. This
>   includes references to:
>
> ```
> Fully qualified class name
> Imported/non-imported class name
> Namespace relative class name
> Import relative class name
> ```

Some other useful StackOverflow answers provide justification for this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30770148/what-is-class-in-php

> It's very useful for 2 reasons.
>
> > You don't have to store your class names in strings anymore. So, many IDEs can retrieve these class names when you refactor your code
> >
> > You can use the `use` keyword to resolve your class and you don't need to write the full class name.
>
> This feature is also useful for Late Static Binding.
>
> Instead of using the `__CLASS__` magic constant, you can use the
>   `static::class` feature to get the name of the derived class inside the
>   parent class.

Then the PHP RFP explain a little bit more about the why the syntax was introduced: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_name_scalars

> The `ClassName::class` syntax was chosen because it can not clash with
>   existing constants (as class is a keyword). The feature addition thus
>   is fully backwards compatible.

And:

> Class names in strings have to be fully qualified in PHP. It is not
>   possible to utilize aliases registered through use statements:

```
use A\Namespaced\ClassName;

// this will try to create a mock of the global class ClassName, not
// of the aliased class A\Namespaced\ClassName
$mock = $this->getMock('ClassName');
```

> `ClassName::class` allows the programmer to easily obtain the fully
>   qualified class name from an aliased name:

```
use A\Namespaced\ClassName;

// ClassName::class resolves to 'A\Namespaced\ClassName'
$mock = $this->getMock(ClassName::class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the dev docs link. Seeing it there officially explains at a proximal level why the pattern is followed. Still not clear on why that's the standard, though. I acknowledged in my question that it makes sense for non-absolute class names, but I'm trying to understand why it's required in lieu of an absolute class name string literal.

Comment: I agree with you. Code Convention is sometime mysterious. To my mind it is for a better maintainability if developers follow some code convention.

Comment: Oh, absolutely. Convention is great; I just like to also know the reasons for it. Generally it's not determined out of the blue. :-)

Comment: Yes sure. To my mind, the possibility to use namespace aliases with ::class is the main reason. You can change the base class without to change all the full class name string in your application.

Comment: I added some source to my answer.

Comment: The point about automatic refactoring makes sense. I know PHPStorm (for example) can sometimes search in strings, but it's a lot less reliable. Accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `::class` works with classes that do not exist, and classes that do exist by are not loadable for some reason.

Add this code anywhere and verify it works without problems

```
echo \ImaginaryNamespace\MyNonExistingClass::class;
```

So, in a sense, it guarantees that you will get a string no matter what, instead of having problems to compile.

Comment: I'm asking why use that instead of just a string literal? Naturally, a string literal will always be a string. :) Edit: realized I hadn't quoted my string in my question. Fixed.